# How to enable LDAP login in docker rundeck?

Tags: docker, ldap, rundeck

I use the following script to start the container, but it keeps using the `realm.properties` instead of the LDAP setup.

The file `jaas-ldap.conf` works as is in rundeck2 which was set up with a different method.
Also, there are no logs generated anywhere, so I can't see what goes wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

local_ip=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')
# MariaDB
db_user="rundeck";
db_pass="_omitted_";
db_root_user="root";
db_root_pass="_omitted_";
db_name="rundeckdb";
maria_docker="mariadb-rundeck";
rundeck_docker="rundeck-docker";
# Docker Images
image="rundeck/rundeck:4.12.0"
im_db="mariadb"

sudo service docker start
docker pull $image
docker pull $im_db
docker container rm -f ${rundeck_docker}
docker container rm -f ${maria_docker}

docker run --name ${maria_docker} \
        -p 3306:3306 \
        -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="${db_root_pass}" \
        -e MYSQL_ROOT_USER="${db_root_user}" \
        -e MYSQL_USER="${db_user}" \
        -e MYSQL_PASSWORD="${db_pass}" \
        -e MYSQL_DATABASE="${db_name}" \
        -v /opt/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql \
        -d $im_db

sleep 3s;

docker run --name ${rundeck_docker} \
        -p 4440:4440 \
        -e RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL=http://${local_ip}:4440 \
        -e SET_CONTAINER_TIMEZONE=Europe/Berlin \
        -e TZ=Europe/Berlin \
        -e RDECK_JVM_OPTS="-Dloginmodule.name=ldap -Dloginmodule.conf.name=jaas-ldap.conf -Drundeck.jaaslogin=true" \
        -e RUNDECK_DATABASE_DRIVER=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver \
        -e RUNDECK_DATABASE_USERNAME="${db_user}" \
        -e RUNDECK_DATABASE_PASSWORD="${db_pass}" \
        -e RUNDECK_DATABASE_URL="jdbc:mysql://${local_ip}:3306/${db_name}?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false" \
        -v "/opt/rundeck/logs:/home/rundeck/var/logs/rundeck" \
        -v "/opt/rundeck/config:/home/rundeck/server/config" \
        -v data:/home/rundeck/server/data $image
```